# Multiple database db2 and sql server with single query

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, db2

The db2 database is called panth01
the sqlserver database is called proof

As you can see in the code, I made a single query, to extract language in db2 and language in sqlserver.

The problem that in Db2 the column is called LANGUAGE
In sqlserver the column is called LINGUA

In db2 the LANGUAGE column has two words "en"
in SqlServer the LINGUA column has three corners "eng"

I made the query:

```
//DB2
private static final String DB_DRIVER_DB2 = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";
private static final String DB_CONNECTION_DB2 = "jdbc:db2://10.12.230.83:50000/PANTH01";
private static final String DB_USER_DB2 = "finance";
private static final String DB_PASSWORD_DB2 = "finance";

//SQLSERVER
private static final String DB_DRIVER_SQLSERVER = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String DB_CONNECTION_SQLSERVER = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.65.21.15:1433;DatabaseName=PROVA";
private static final String DB_USER_SQLSERVER = "sa";
private static final String DB_PASSWORD_SQLSERVER = "sa";

public void selectTHERACLASS_HDR_THERACLASS_HDR_NLS() throws Exception {

//DB2_inizio
Connection dbConnection = null;
Statement statement = null;
//DB2_fine

//SqlServer_inzio
Connection dbConnectionSqlServer = null;
Statement statementSqlServer = null;
//SqlServer_fine

//Query SqlServer and db2
String query = "select PANTH01.THERA.CLASS_HDR.LANGUAGE, PROVA.DIZIOPT.LINGUA from PANTH01.THERA.CLASS_HDR JOIN PROVA.DIZIOPT.LINGUA ON PANTH01.THERA.CLASS_HDR.LANGUAGE = PROVA.DIZIOPT.LINGUA";

try {
//DB2_inizio
dbConnection = getConnectionDb2();
statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
//DB2_fine

//sqlserver_inizio
dbConnectionSqlServer = getConnectionSqlServer();
statementSqlServer = dbConnectionSqlServer.createStatement();
ResultSet rSqlServer = statementSqlServer.executeQuery(query);
//sqlserver_inizio_fine

while (rSqlServer.next()) {


String language = rSqlServer.getString("LANGUAGE");
String lingua = rSqlServer.getString("LINGUA");

System.out.println("LANGUAGE: " + language);
System.out.println("LINGUA: " + lingua);
}

} catch (SQLException e) {

System.out.println(e.getMessage());

} finally {

if (statement != null && statementSqlServer != null) {
statement.close();
statementSqlServer.close();
}

if (dbConnection != null && dbConnectionSqlServer != null) {
dbConnection.close();
dbConnectionSqlServer.close();
}
}
}
```

Output
Invalid object name 'PANTH01.THERA.CLASS_HDR'

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use the `dbConnectionSqlServer` to refer to a DB2 table on a completely different machine. That won't work unless you create a "Linked Server" in the SQL Server instance that points to the DB2 database.

Comment: how can I create a connection between db2 and sql server?
An example in jdbc?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: this information is not enough, I need some concrete examples